# set body of email as html format

Tags: symfony

I have following code to send the mail

```php
use Ens\NewBundle\Controller\Services\MyMailers as MyMailers;

function NotificationOnSignUp($z)
{
    $x = new MyMailers;
    $x->setToloc($z['to']);
    $x->setFromloc('ucerturohit@gmail.com');
    $x->setSubject('Wonderful world');
    $x->setBody('Hello world');

    $z = $x->mail();

    if($z==1) {
        $name = 'success';
    } else {
        $name = 'failed';
    }

    return $x->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:ind.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    // return $z;  
}
```

I want to set the template file `ind.html.twig` as the body of the mail. This function is not in the controller and I dont want to use any service.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the string resulting from rendering a template using:

```
$container->get('templating')->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:ind.html.twig', array('name' => $name))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess my answer is 2-years delayed, but maybe for someone else this will be helpful:
this is a special Sf2 bundle for sending mails from twig templates [Symfony2-MailerBundle](https://github.com/umbrella-web/Symfony2-MailerBundle).
The bundle also allows to set up sending parameters in config file & you won't have to pass them every time you want to build & send email.